# Auditing pyspark jobs

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, audit, audit-logging

I have created a job in pyspark and now I want to audit my job. What are the factors that I need to consider while auditing job? What all things do I need to log for auditing.? It would be really helpful if I get some reference links. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could explain, what do you mean when you want to audit the job?

Comment: Hi @AnandVidvat 

Thanks for your response. Means I want to log all the information related to a spark job like job_name, job_time, no_of_errors etc. So what are all the things that can be logged as mentioned above.